# Is there a way to give aliases to all the time series indices in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I saw that following is the way to add aliases for one index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-aliases.html

Time series indices are usually formed everyday as per configuration, so how to give aliases those individual indices keeping the date part as it is?

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down the page you linked to a little bit, you'll find that you can do what you want using a glob pattern (i.e. `time*`)

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "time*", "alias" : "all_time_indices" } }
    ]
}
```

Note, however, that if a new time series index is created it won't get the alias automatically. For that you'd need to set up an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html) instead:

```
PUT _template/my-time-series
{
  "index_patterns": ["time*"],
  "aliases": {
     "all_time_indices": {}
  },
  "settings": {
    ...
  },
  "mappings": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Will try it. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val if i use this way to change aliases like this, then alias wont have dates right. All requests will go to all_time_indices, not specific day index.

Comment: Feel free to update your question to explain your exact use case in more details.